# while running the flutter app i am getting this error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-test, jitsi

Type mismatch: inferred type is Activity? but Activity was expected

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':jitsi_meet:compileReleaseKotlin'.

> Compilation error. See log for more details

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

Answer (score 0):

If you have not added kotlin configuration, then plz add below line in android/build file

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
.
.
.
```

And also add classpath right as below:

```
dependencies {
classpath 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.10'
.
.
.
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you be more specific on what and where is this problem happening.
This error is telling you that the type expected is `Activity` instead of the nullable type `Activity?`.